# Laravel 7 failed method not running on retrying failed jobs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-queue

I have a simple Laravel Job, that will upload a video to the cloud, the issue is that the Queue Server isn't retrying on job failure. I've tried throwing an exception, but didn't get any luck. I'm running the queue server in background with this command:

```
nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon --timeout=0 > ./storage/logs/laravel-queue.log 2>&1 &
```

Here's my simple code for debugging:

```php
class UploadVideoToCDN implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 3;
public $maxAttempts = 4;

    private $request;
    private $userId;
    private $currQuestion;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(array $request, string $id)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->userId = $id;
       
    }
    /**
     * Handle a job failure.
     *
     * @param  Throwable  $exception
     * @return void
     */
    public  function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
        $attempts = $this->attempts();
        Log::emergency("JOB FAILED at " . $attempts . " attempts");
        if($attempts < 3){
            $this->currQuestion->videoTranscodeStatus = "failed-retry";
            $this->currQuestion->save();
Log::debug("releasing a new job");
            // $this->release(2);
        }else {
            $this->currQuestion->videoTranscodeStatus = "failed";
            $this->currQuestion->save();
            $disk = config('temporary_files_disk');
            $fullpath = Storage::disk($disk)->path($this->path);
            Log::alert("Deleting temporary video: " . $fullpath);
            Storage::disk($disk)->delete($this->path);
            $this->delete();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        try {
            Log::alert("Initiated upload video job");
sleep(20);
throw new \Exception("some error");
} catch($e) {
throw new Exception($e);
}
}
```

My Queue Config:

```php
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Queue Connection Name
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel's queue API supports an assortment of back-ends via a single
    | API, giving you convenient access to each back-end using the same
    | syntax for every one. Here you may define a default connection.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Queue Connections
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure the connection information for each server that
    | is used by your application. A default configuration has been added
    | for each back-end shipped with Laravel. You are free to add more.
    |
    | Drivers: "sync", "database", "beanstalkd", "sqs", "redis", "null"
    |
    */

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'your-queue-name'),
            'suffix' => env('SQS_SUFFIX'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Failed Queue Jobs
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | These options configure the behavior of failed queue job logging so you
    | can control which database and table are used to store the jobs that
    | have failed. You may change them to any database / table you wish.
    |
    */

    'failed' => [
        'driver' => env('QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER', 'database'),
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],

];
```

Env variables

```
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
QUEUE_DRIVER=database
```

Queue server logs:

```
[2022-03-16 14:04:42][293] Processing: App\Jobs\UploadVideoToCDN
[2022-03-16 14:05:03][294] Processing: App\Jobs\UploadVideoToCDN
[2022-03-16 14:05:23][295] Processing: App\Jobs\UploadVideoToCDN
[2022-03-16 14:05:44][295] Failed:     App\Jobs\UploadVideoToCDN
```

Apprently, it does get retried, but the failed only called after all retries, how can I call the fail method on every retry?

Comment: Can you show us ```queue.php``` aswell, I believe it is in config folder.

Comment: Added the config

Comment: In your .env what have you supplied for ```QUEUE_CONNECTION``` and ```QUEUE_FAILED_DRIVER``` ?

Comment: These are all the variables related to queue in .env

Comment: And in your database you do have a ```jobs``` and ```failed_jobs``` table, or something along those lines. I don't know if you've changed any defaults.

Comment: Yes, it has those tables. Sometimes, it gets retried, but for only once.